# Selenium cannot access actions in BasePage of my framework

Tags: c#, selenium, page-factory

I currently have a framework that start off on the `LoginPage.cs` and performs the actions to log the user into the system which in turn takes them to the `DashboardPage.cs`. On the `DashboardPage.cs` there is the utility navigation bar at the top of the page which will appear on all the pages. So what I have done is separated the common actions to `PolicyBasePage.cs` which should be accessible by all other page apart from the `LoginPage.cs`.

My testmethod breaks when is gets to `dashboardPage.PolicyBasePage.SearchButton();` and I get the following error message:

> Message: Test method TestAutomationFrameworkPOMS.TestScript.Tests.Test
>   threw exception:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

TestMethod.cs:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    NavigationHelper.NavigateToUrl(ObjectRepository.Config.GetWebsite());

    var loginPage = new LoginPage();
    loginPage.UsernameTextBox(ObjectRepository.Config.GetUsername());
    loginPage.PasswordTextBox(ObjectRepository.Config.GetPassword());
    loginPage.RememberMeCheckBox();
    loginPage.LoginButton();

    var dashboardPage = new DashboardPage();
    dashboardPage.PolicyBasePage.SearchButton();

    var searchPage = new SearchPage();
    searchPage.QuotePolicyNumberTextBox("0005");
    searchPage.SearchButton();

    var transACTPage = new TransACTPage();
    transACTPage.PostCodeTextBox("MTA");
    transACTPage.GoButton();
    GenericHelper.TakeScreenshot();
}
```

DashboardPage.cs:

```cs
public class DashboardPage
{
    private IWebElement driver;
    public PolicyBasePage PolicyBasePage { get; set; }

    #region WebElements

    #endregion

    public DashboardPage()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(ObjectRepository.Driver, this);
    }

    #region Actions

    #endregion
}
```

PolicyBasePage.cs:

```cs
public class PolicyBasePage
{
    #region WebElement

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "id_Search")]
    private IWebElement Search;

    #endregion

    public PolicyBasePage()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(ObjectRepository.Driver, this);
    }

    #region

    public void SearchButton()
    {
        Search.Click();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before you make the call to:

```
dashboardPage.PolicyBasePage.SearchButton();
```

you only create a new dashboardPage object I cant see this inheriting your PolicyBasePage anywhere. You have not created a PolicyBasePage Object, that I can see. You could create this in a dashboardPage Initialiser method.

Comment: Sorry im not quite sure what you mean, I tried to add `new PolicyBasePage()` in the following method `public DashboardPage()` but i am receiving the same error message